# How to create function that accepts lambda expression in python?

Tags: python, lambda

How do I create a function which accepts lambda expression like,

```
# dummy data
data = [{"dim":["abc","sdc"], "mea":[23,23,134]},{"dim":["jgdf","dfc"], "mea":[34,245,2345]}....]

"""
also note that data may be change, [{"x":[{"dim":["abc","sdc"], "mea":[23,23,134]},{"dim":["jgdf","dfc"], "mea":[34,245,2345]}....], "y":.....},...]

but data structure (dictionary) for keys "dim" & "mea" will remain same.
"""  

def function(data,key=lambda x: x):
    """
    Logic:

    sum1 = sum(i["mea"][0] for i in data)

    return [[data[i]["dim"],data[i]["mea"][0]] for i in range(len(data)) if data[i]["mea"][0] * len(data) / sum1 > 1]

    now i want equivalent lambda function that works for any data 
    constraint is that structure before "dim" & "mea" will change.
    """
```

how do i create that type of function?

Any help that is appreciated.

Comment: You already did. What's the problem?

Comment: i had modified my question please check.

Comment: Sorry, it's really hard to follow. The comment in the function doesn't correspond to function's arguments. I don't get to what do you want the lambda to be equivalent to.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda can be treated like any regular variable that is callable:

```
def function(data, f):
   return f(data)
```

In your case to create a max function:

```
def max(data, key = lambda x: x):
  m = lambda a,b: a if key(a) > key(b) else b
  return reduce(m, data)
```

or more verbose:

```
def max(data, key = lambda x: x):
  max_ = data[0]
  for d in data:
    if key(d) > key(max_): max_ = d
  return max_
```

How to optimize this to avoid calling `key` too often is left as an exercise for the reader.

**More Examples**

Max:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a,b: a if a['hi'] > b['hi'] else b, [{"hi":0},{"hi":-1},{"hi":9}])
{'hi': 9}
```

Sum:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a,b: {"hi":a["hi"]+b["hi"]}, [{"hi":1},{"hi":2},{"hi":3}])
{'hi': 6}
```

More generic:

```
>>> def generic(data, f, key = lambda x: x, cons = lambda x: x):
...    return reduce(lambda a,b: cons(f(key(a),key(b))), data)
... 
>>> generic([{"hi":1},{"hi":2},{"hi":3}], lambda a,b: a*b, key = lambda x: x["hi"], cons = lambda x: {"hi":x})
{'hi': 6}

>>> def generic_select(data, f, key = lambda x: x):
...   return reduce(lambda a,b: a if f(key(a), key(b)) else b, data)
... 
>>> generic_select([{"hi":1,"a":"b"},{"hi":0,"a":"c"}], lambda a,b: True if a < b else False, key = lambda x: x["hi"])
{'a': 'c', 'hi': 0}
```

It depends on what you actually want to do. If you want a reduction that applies a bin op use `generic` if you want a reduction that decides between taking a,b use `generic_select`.

**Reduce**

Reduce isn't available in python3 without an import but you can import it from the functools package. It's a very common and simple pattern:

```
>>> def reduce_(data, f):
...   r = data[0]
...   for r_ in data[1:]:
...     r = f(r, r_)
...   return r
... 
>>> reduce_([1,2,3], lambda a,b: a+b)
6
>>> reduce_([1,2,3], lambda a,b: a if a > b else b)
3
```

Sometimes it may be necessary to specify an initial value instead of using `data[0]`:

```
>>> def reduce1(data, init, f):
...   r = init
...   for r_ in data:
...     r = f(r, r_)
...   return r
... 
>>> reduce1([1,2,3], [], lambda a,b: [b]+a)
[3, 2, 1]
```

A reduction of `lambda a,b: [b]+a` reverses a list. `reduce` means to reduce a list of values to a single value.